# pip install python3-memcached fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, memcached

When I try to install python3-memcached using the following command,

```
pip install python3-memcahed
```

It fails with the following error output,

```
Collecting python3-memcached  
Using cached python3-memcached-1.51.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/pl/5d9_g9ld38d9r_36fhqwzzb40000gp/T/pip-build-UuR8g9/python3-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import memcache
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/pl/5d9_g9ld38d9r_36fhqwzzb40000gp/T/pip-build-UuR8g9/python3-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>

    import memcache

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pl/5d9_g9ld38d9r_36fhqwzzb40000gp/T/pip-build-UuR8g9/python3-memcached
```

The file path specified in the above error does not exist.

FYI: I used brew to install python3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following (with sudo):

```
sudo pip3 install python3-memcached
```

For python3 packages it is better to use pip3. If you don't have it installed, type:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: That was awesome... "pip3" did it!

Answer (score 1):

In cse nyone bumps into this one in the future, if you are using virtualenvs it may help if you create your virtualenv as:

```
mkvirtualenv myenv --python=`which python3`
```